# Wordpress do_shortcode strange behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am developing a WP plugin which processes shortcodes and displays amazon item data in place of them. The plugin is working as desired, except for a little strange behavior. You can see my test run at http://passivetest.themebandit.com/test-post-for-zon-plugin/ .

If you scroll down on that page, you can see that 4 "1" s are appended to the content. The shortcode is processed 4 times in this page, and each time WP is adding an undesired `1` to the output. I don't understand why this is happening. There is no "1" anywhere in my html files, and its nowhere in the post content. All my functions just return the content that is to be replaced in place of the shortcode. Can someone please give an explanation for it and let me know how to remove these? Thanks in advance..

My code is as follows:

```
add_shortcode('zon_product', 'zon_process_shortcode');

// Zon Shortcode processor
function zon_process_shortcode($attributes, $content = null) {
    global $zon_html_path;

    // default options for shortcode
    $options = array('asin' => '', 'style' => 'compact', 'loc' => 'com');
    extract(shortcode_atts($options, $attributes));

    $asin = $attributes['asin'];

    // first find asin in local zon_data table
    $zdb = ZonDbHandler::instance();
    $product = $zdb->findASIN($asin);

    if ($product) {
        // if product exists in db, render template
        return zon_display_product($product, $attributes);
    } else {
        // product does not exist in database, get data through amazon api worflow
        $product = ZonLibrary::getAmazonProduct($asin, $attributes['loc']);
        if ($product) {
            // product data has been successfully retrieved and saved, render template
            return zon_display_product($product, $attributes);
        } else {
            // error in fetching product data, check amazon access key id and api secret
            $content = include($zon_html_path . 'html' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'api_error.php');
            return $content;
        }
    }
}

// Renders selected template with product data
function zon_display_product(ZonProduct $product, $attributes) {
    global $zon_html_path;
    global $zon_path;

    // process other shortcode options
    $view_vars = array();
    $view_vars['style'] = (isset($attributes['style'])) ? $attributes['style'] : "default";
    $view_vars['show_price'] = (isset($attributes['show_price']) && $attributes['show_price'] == 0) ? false : true;
    $view_vars['price_updates'] = (isset($attributes['price_updates']) && $attributes['price_updates'] == 0) ? false : true;
    $view_vars['hide_unavailable'] = (isset($attributes['hide_unavailable']) && $attributes['hide_unavailable'] == 1) ? true : false;
    $view_vars['show_desc'] = (isset($attributes['show_desc']) && $attributes['show_desc'] == 0) ? false : true;

    // check if template file exists
    if (!is_file($zon_html_path . 'html' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $view_vars['style'] . '.php')) {
        $content = 'ERROR! Zon Template not found. Please check you are using a correct value for the "style" parameter.';
        return $content;
    } else {
        // get product array
        $product = $product->getArray();

        // if product is unavailable and hide_unavailable is true, return unavailable template
        if ($view_vars['hide_unavailable']) {
            if ((strpos($product['availability'], "Usually") === false) && strpos($product['availability'], "ships") === false) {
                $content = include($zon_html_path . 'html' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'unavailable.php');
                return $content;
            }
        }

        // render chosen template file
        $content = include($zon_html_path . 'html' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $view_vars['style'] . '.php');
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that something else is responsible for appearance of the '1' characters. If you view the source, what is actually being generated is `<p style="color: #141412;">1</p>`. I don't think Wordpress would generate that on its own. Searching for that style string in your plugin and/or theme folder should find your culprit.

Comment: Okay.. let me quickly do a grep and see if I find any..

Comment: I did a 'grep -rn "141412" .' in my wp-content folder and it could only find these:

./themes/twentythirteen/css/editor-style.css:36:        color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:110:  color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:576:  color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:819:  color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:872:  color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:1037: color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:2888:         color: #141412;
./themes/twentythirteen/style.css:2895:         color: #141412;

Its not in my plugin..

Comment: The number of 1s that are generated is equal to the number of shortcodes I have in my post content.. when I use 3 shortcodes there are 3 1s etc..

Comment: Hmmm. Nothing I can see in what you've posted here would generate the `1` characters. What does your shortcode look like in the post?

Comment: Just 4 shortcodes.. this:

[zon_product asin="0470170778" loc="usa"][/zon_product]

[zon_product style="compact" asin="B00HWHXQSC" loc="usa"][/zon_product]

[zon_product style="default" asin="B00GOBPD10" loc="usa"][/zon_product]

[zon_product style="large" price_updates=0 show_price=0 asin="0321444426" loc="usa"][/zon_product]

Comment: Have you tried omitting the closing `[/zon_product]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59908/discussion-between-ananth-and-cpilko).